# simplify this PHP code?

Tags: php

any ideas?
in the second case $v is an array
I could do is_array($v), but I'd have to repeat the if/else anyway

```
foreach(array('city', 'location') as $f) {
        $ors[$f] = array();

        if (!isset($_POST[$f])) continue;

        $v = $_POST[$f];
        if (isset($df[$f][$v])) {
                array_push($ors[$f], $df[$f][$v]);
        }
        else {
                security_error();
        }
}

foreach(array('age', 'sex') as $f) {
        $ors[$f] = array();

        if (!isset($_POST[$f])) continue;

        foreach($_POST[$f] as $v) {
                if (isset($df[$f][$v])) {
                        array_push($ors[$f], $df[$f][$v]);
                }
                else {
                        security_error();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite like how the code is set up. What does `security_error()` do? Also, what is `$df`?

Answer (score 2):

Use ternary conditional operator for both loops:

```
$result = isset($df[$f][$v]) ? array_push($ors[$f], $df[$f][$v]) : security_error();
```

and/or for the function:

```
function pushIfSetOrSecurityError($source, $target, $key) {
    $result = isset($source[$key]) ? array_push($target, $source[$key]) : security_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function pushIfSetOrSecurityError($source, $target, $key) {
        if (isset($source[$key]))
                array_push($target, $source[$key]);
        else
                security_error();
}

foreach(array('city', 'location') as $f) {
        $ors[$f] = array();
        if (isset($_POST[$f]))
                pushIfSetOrSecurityError($df[$f], $ors[$f], $_POST[$f]);
}

foreach(array('age', 'sex') as $f) {
        $ors[$f] = array();
        if (isset($_POST[$f]))
                foreach($_POST[$f] as $v)
                        pushIfSetOrSecurityError($df[$f], $ors[$f], $v);
}
```